# Unable to turn the silent mode in Gionee A1 programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hey there I am using below code to **turn the device into silence mode**.

```
public static void setDeviceOnSilent(Context context) {

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

The above code work well in all device except **Gionee A1**. Please suggest what is the problem i already given the **NotificationAccessPolicyEnabled** Permission. below is the code.

```
public static boolean isNotificationAccessPolicyEnabled(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

        context.startActivity(intent);

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the api level running on device ??

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty much alright. Check the manifest for the necessary permissions.